# Save Python .npz as MATLAB .mat file

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I have a `.npz` file that I would like to save as a `.mat` file.

The file `A.npz` contains `A['arr_0', 'arr_1', 'arr_2']`

Currently, I am saving each one individually using the following:

```
import scipy.io as sio
a1 = A['arr_0']
sio.savemat('a1.mat', mdict={'a1': a1}
```

for each `arr_i` within `A.npz`.

Is there a simple way to save all the contents into a `.mat` (i.e. via cell format)? Or should I just create a script to simply save them all in a loop like fashion?

Comment: Given that you supply these two options I presume you tried both, so you know which one is faster and/or better for your use case. So what is your question?

Comment: Is there a simple command to save the entire `A.npz` dataset into a single `.mat` file, without going through a loop script? Sorry, I thought I was clear. I am new to Python, so I am not sure if I am missing something basic here.

Comment: That is unfortunately [not on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). We help with concrete programming problems, not design questions or documentation requests (wich this boils down to).

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to load each array from the `npz` into memeory (`npz` is a lazy loader).  Then you can save all the arrays to the `mat` as multiitem dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `npz`:

```
In [147]: np.savez('test.npz',x=np.arange(3),y=np.ones((3,3)),z=np.array(3))
```

load; `data` is the dictionary of files/variables; load by indexing:

```
In [148]: data = np.load('test.npz')
In [149]: list(data.keys())
Out[149]: ['z', 'y', 'x']
In [150]: data['x']
Out[150]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

Save a similar dictionary to the .mat:

```
In [151]: io.savemat('a1.mat', mdict={'x':data['x'],'y':data['y'],'z':data['z']})
In [152]: io.loadmat('a1.mat')
Out[152]: 
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Thu Feb 15 09:52:42 2018',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'x': array([[0, 1, 2]]),
 'y': array([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]),
 'z': array([[3]])}
```

alternative constructs:

```
io.savemat('a1.mat', mdict={key:data[key] for key in data.keys()})
```

or even:

```
io.savemat('a1.mat', mdict=data)
```

since `data` is a dictionary.

Comment: Looks like the `load` dictionary can be passed directly to the `loadmat`.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner for shell scripts, etc.:

```
python -c "import pylab, scipy.io; scipy.io.savemat('tmp.mat', pylab.np.load('tmp.npz'))"
```